# Specify specific color scheme and dpi when save a pdf

Tags: python, node.js, pdf, pdfkit, pypdf

I'm testing pdf generation using 2 different technologies\libraries:

1. PyPDF2 (python - https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2)
2. pdfkit (NodeJs - https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit)

What I've to do is to save a PDF with specific color scheme like FOGRA39 (http://www.color.org/fogra39.xalter). I have to do this to be sure that when we print it using industrial printers, the colors (CMYK) will be exactly the same of pdf.
Furthermore I have to set 300 dpi to the pdf.
I didn't find documentation about this operations.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance